# I have an error containing .length and .charAt with a token infront. Why won't it work?

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I don't know what is wrong with my code. The .length and .charAt are underlined red.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

//CREATE FILES

File file = new File("DATA21.txt");

Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

int vowels = 0;

while (input.hasNext()) {

StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input.nextLine());

for (int i = 0; i < st.length(); i++) {

if (st.charAt(i) == 'a' || st.charAt(i) == 'e' || st.charAt(i) == 'i' || st.charAt(i) == 'o' || st.charAt(i) == 'u') {

vowels++;

}

}



}
```

Comment: You tagged this as JavaScript. Did you mean Java?

Comment: `st` is a `StringTokenizer`, not a `String`.

Comment: There seems to be no reason to use a ```StringTokenizer``` here.

Comment: So how would I seperate the strings in the file into different words so that it counts the vowels for each word in the file. Right know my output is this: 8
11
19
27
69                                                                                                                        
 and the words in the file are: 
mathematics computerops
jackal truck
waterloo saturdaii
nsomniac extermin                                                             
aaeuaoiuaeuaioiuaeiuao oeiiueiuaoiuaueiioiua

Answer (score 1):

The StringTokenizer class is used to split a String into multiple Tokens. That is not what you want to do. The nextLine() Method returns a String which is not at all the same as StringTokenizer. Use the following

```
String myString = input.nextLine()
```